# Objective-C: Are blocks defined inside of methods strong or weak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency, block

I have a situation like this:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    void (^myBlock1)(void) = ^{
        // ... do stuff
    };

    void (^myBlock2)(void) = ^{
        [weakSelf doSomeHeavyNetworkCall2:^{
            myBlock1();
        }];
    };

    [self doSomeHeavyNetworkCall1:^{
        myBlock2();
    }];
}
```

What is the life cycle of myBlock1 and myBlock2 in this case? Should I be checking for nil like this?

```
void (^myBlock2)(void) = ^{
    [weakSelf doSomeHeavyNetworkCall2:^{
        if (myBlock1) {
            myBlock1();
        }
    }];
};

[self doSomeHeavyNetworkCall1:^{
    if (myBlock2) {
        myBlock2();
    }
}];
```

Also if I wrap the entire `someMethod` in `@synchronized`, am I guaranteed to have the blocks around?

Comment: Re wrapping `someMethod` in `@synchronized`, note that if these blocks run asynchronously, they will not be synchronized. The `@synchronized` directive only affects that which runs synchronously. If your intent is to  synchronize the callbacks, you have to put `@synchronized` directives _inside_ the blocks, not wrapping `someMethod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are strong by default in Objective-C so `myBlock1` and `myBlock2` are strong. There is no need for the `if (myBlock1)` and `if (myBlock2)` checks.

Wrapping the contents of `someMethod` with `@synchronized` has no effect on the lifecycle of these variables.

Comment: Thank you. So if they are retained, that means this instance is retained also. Does that mean I don't need to have `__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;` and `[weakSelf doSomeHeavyNetworkCall2:^{` either?

Comment: The use of the `weakSelf` is a completely separate issue related to potential reference cycles. But that has nothing to do with the `myBlock1` and `myBlock2` variables.